# list emr clusters using go

Tags: go, amazon-emr, aws-sdk-go

I'm trying to list emr clusters using go.

Here is the code I have that is returning blank.  I did "the same" in python with correct results.

```
running := "RUNNING"

waiting := "WAITING"

emr_states := []*string {&running, &waiting}

var abc emr.ListClustersInput

abc.SetClusterStates(emr_states)

sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())

svc := emr.New(sess)

list_clusters_output, err := svc.ListClusters(&abc)

_ = err


println(fmt.Sprintf("type of list clusters output is %s", reflect.TypeOf(list_clusters_output)))

println(fmt.Sprintf("type of *list clusters output is %s", reflect.TypeOf(*list_clusters_output)))


list_clusters_output_dereffed := *list_clusters_output

println(list_clusters_output_dereffed.String())
```

The output I'm getting is

```
type of list clusters output is *emr.ListClustersOutput
type of *list clusters output is emr.ListClustersOutput
{
}
```

There is a cluster running that I have successfully returned with a python script.

Comment: have you checked `err`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  I was missing region indication in the session.

Full solution below.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/emr" 
)

func main() {

    starting := "STARTING"

    running := "RUNNING"

    waiting := "WAITING"

    emr_states := []*string {&starting, &running, &waiting}
    
    var abc emr.ListClustersInput
    
    abc.SetClusterStates(emr_states)

    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())

    reggie := "us-east-1"

    sess.Config.Region = &reggie

    svc := emr.New(sess)

    list_clusters_output, err := svc.ListClusters(&abc)

    if err != nil {
        println(err.Error())
    }

    list_clusters_output_dereffed := *list_clusters_output

    println(list_clusters_output_dereffed.GoString())
    
}
```